# How do I unregister OCX and delete it after uninstall requested with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, ocx

I currently use the following code to store my OCX file and register it when install requested by using the following code:

```
[Files]
Source: "Myfile.ocx"; DestDir: "{localappdata}\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion regserver uninsneveruninstall noregerror
```

I need to know how to unregister/remove `Myfile.ocx` after or while  uninstalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup uninstaller does uninstall files by default.

Inno Setup uninstaller does unregister the DLL/OCX files by default, it they were installed with a [`regserver` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=regserver):

> **regserver**
>
> Register the DLL/OCX file. With this flag set, Setup will call the DllRegisterServer function exported by the DLL/OCX file, **and the uninstaller will call DllUnregisterServer prior to removing the file.** When used in combination with `sharedfile`, the DLL/OCX file will only be unregistered when the reference count reaches zero.

---

But you are preventing it from doing so by an [`uninsneveruninstall` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=uninsneveruninstall):

> **uninsneveruninstall**
>
> Never remove the file. This flag can be useful when installing very common shared files that shouldn't be deleted under any circumstances, such as MFC DLLs.
>
> Note that if this flag is combined with the `sharedfile` flag, the file will never be deleted at uninstall time but the reference count will still be properly decremented.

Just remove the `uninsneveruninstall` flag.